# Authentication Google Pages in .NET MVC3 App to get page source

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am writing an MVC3 app that is trying to get the page source of a google page (specifically the Android Marketplace for our company) that is behind the authentication wall. I am just wondering how I can authenticate properly so that my app can see pages that are authenticated.

I tried following the steps at this site (post by WeCi2i): http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/870187-login-youtube-using-c, but without success.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft included by default DotNetOpenAuth in MVC 4, but you can use it also in MVC 3

http://dotnetopenauth.net/

http://www.tkglaser.net/2012/02/single-sign-on-using-google-in-asp-mvc.html

Comment: Is it possible to do this entirely in code though? Every example wants user input, but I am looking to just hard code the username and password.

Comment: sorry,I haven't really played with it, just a few times. you need to read the documents.